# Show that a function is continuous iff it is constant

Tags: real-analysis

show that a function from $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric to $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric is continuous if and only if it is constant.

The solution states to use the $\epsilon,  \delta$ definition to show that $f$ is piecewise constant, then use the derivative of $f$ to explain why $f$ is constant.

I'm having troubles understand this solution, what I take it as, I have to show that $f$ is continuous $\implies$ f is constant. So, $f$ being continuous in these two metric spaces means that $\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists \delta > 0, \text{ s.t. }  |x-y|< \delta \text{ and } x,y \in \mathbb{R} \implies d(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$? If so, I'm not sure how to go about showing $f$ is constant from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $\epsilon = 1/2$. Then
$$
d_{discrete}(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon \iff f(x) = f(y)
$$

Comment: Hi, where did you get that from? My definition of discrete is that $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$ and $d(x,y) = 1$ otherwise

Comment: @DH. Yes.  So, if $d(x,y)<\frac{1}{2}$, you must have $d(x,y)=0$.  Hence $x=y$.